# Che cosa vuol dire la frase "mal della pietra" in questo senso figurato?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Sto leggendo un libro sulla storia d'Italia e mi sono imbattuto nella frase "mal della pietra". Facendo delle ricerche su Internet ho scoperto che si tratta di un'espressione abbastanza (o forse molto) insolita, e non sono riuscito a trovare il significato esatto. L'espressione figura in una descrizione dell'epoca in cui il *limes* (cioè, la frontiera fortificata dell'Impero romano) diventava sempre meno efficace per proteggere l'Impero dalle tribù barbariche. Ecco il brano:

> Più frequenti si facevano i raid dei barbari, più larghe le brecce nel *limes*, e più nei Romani si sviluppava il mal della pietra per tappare i buchi.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Potrebbe intendere una specie di ossessione nell'edificare muri su muri in pietra per fortificare le frontiere?

Comment: Puoi dirci di quale  libro si tratta?

Comment: @Benedetta Il brano è tratto da uno dei volumi di _Storia d'Italia_ di Indro Montanelli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il significato di **mal della pietra** corrisponde all’odierna calcolosi o litiasi.

> Persino Ippocrate doveva aver osservato questa patologia, tanto che
>   nel famoso giuramento del medico che prende il suo nome, è presente
>   questa frase: “Non opererò coloro che soffrono del male della pietra,
>   ma mi rivolgerò a coloro che sono esperti di questa attività”.

Questo non solo a causa dell'alta probabilità di complicanze intra e postoperatorie (come emorragie o infezioni) ma anche per evitare che il medico diventasse chirurgo: due professioni ben distinte nell'antichità.

In senso figurato nel passaggio da te indicato l’espressione vuol dire che più si aprivano brecce nelle difese dei Romani più questi ultimi si affliggevano nel porre rimedio.

Questa ossessione diventava paragonabile alla patologia in oggetto che, a quei tempi, era difficile da curare e aveva molto spesso esito infausto.

Comment: Potresti indicarci la fonte?

Comment: Ho trovato [questa citazione](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqj8TDrazYAhXGOxQKHb0GAIIQFghjMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fit.answers.yahoo.com%2Fquestion%2Findex%3Fqid%3D20080417100109AAXkgzn&usg=AOvVaw2XjPU8OrFCw6POHrhbwDf4) in cui si dice che anticamente il significato era più esteso e comprendeva ansia, depressioni e comportamenti bizzarri. Non so quanto sia attendibile la fonte ma sto cercando un riferimento più autorevole.